Improving the performance of dynamically allocated matrices
I am writing a program to do some linear algebra calculations on 300 x 300 complex matrices using the eigen library. I have a family of matrices, which can be thought of as a function of some parameter. Since the matrices are large, I think I would need to allocate them dynamically (via heap allocation). My code is as follows:
for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    Eigen::Matrix<complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> matrix = compute_matrix(i);
    // Doing calculations
}

Instead of allocating a new object dynamically for each iteration of the loop, would it be possible to allocate an Eigen matrix once, and then reuse it for each iteration of the loop?
More context:
I need to diagonalize a large number of 300 x 300 matrices. Each matrix is defined as:
M = x * A + B 

where A and B are two other matrices and "x" is a complex variable.
Here is a more detailed description:
std::vector<Eigen::Vector<double>> eigenvalue_vector(1000);
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix<complex<double>, Dynamic, Dynamic>> solver;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    Matrix<complex<double>, Dynamic, Dynamic> M = x * A + B;
    solver.compute(M)
    eigenvalue_vector[i] = solver.eigenvalues()
    // Time-consuming calculations based on the eigenvalues and eigenvectors 

}

I would like this code to be as efficient as possible, since I have to do the same calculation for a large number of 300 x 300 matrices, each one constructed using a different "x". Later on, I am going to use MPI or OMP to parallelize the for loop. However, I have been wondering if there are some performance tips that are applicable in this case.

It is hard to understand what is asked here. Is it possible to define object outside of loop instead of defining it inside of loop? Yes, it is. Does it alter performance? Needs profiling but unlikely as for unknown "compute_matrix(i)" there will anyway be a temporary matrix created and there is unknown "doing calculations" that sounds like something that takes some time.

You do not need to heap-allocate. The Eigen::Matrix class already holds a pointer to heap-allocated memory.

Unless my math is wrong, a 300x300 matrix of complex works out to 1.6 MB. If you need all of them simultaneously , that's only 750 MB for the lot...

If you want to avoid that compute_matrix allocates a new object every iteration, you can allocate the matrix outside the loop and pass it by (non-const) reference to that method. Without more context it is difficult to judge if that makes a significant difference in your case.

Thanks   I have added more detailed description of my problem. I have solved the same problem in fortran and it was faster than in my C++. I am in the process of learning C++ so I am not 100% sure if this is the best way to solve this problem. Also, I am wondering how pointers can speed up this calculation? Also, would it be possible to use stack-allocated matrices for this problem?

Eigen::Matrix is statically-allocated if the sizes are known at compile-time, otherwise, and this is your case, it is dynamically-allocated.

I know the size at compile time. The only reason I am using dynamic matrices is because they are somewhat big. I receive an error saying that it is not possible to allocate Eigen matrices of that particular size on the stack.

AFAIK, in Eigen operations are templated expression to avoid creating/allocating temporary matrices. Thus, doing M = ... force the creation of the matrix due to its type. Based on this, you can just store the result in auto M = ...; where the type of M is a template expression. Because of that, functions like solver.compute needs to accept such templated expression (most Eigen function does but not all).

An alternative solution is to still write data in the M matrix but to preallocate once. You just need to move the creation of M outside the loop with Matrix<complex<double>, Dynamic, Dynamic> M(300, 300);. Then, filling M with M = x * A + B might not allocate a new matrix (I am not sure the LHS need a method to ensure that). A way to be sure not to create a matrix could be to use matrix reference like Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>>.

See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Expression_templates regarding "expression templates".

This won't work: eigenvalue_vector[i] = solver.eigenvalues() (besides the missing ;) You can't assign a Eigen::VectorXd to a double. When posting a [mre] make sure that it actually compiles and reproduces your problem. Also what compiler and what compiler arguments are you using?

Unrelated to performance issues: Are you sure that M = x * A + B is self-adjoint in your case? For arbitrary complex x this is quite unlikely ...

it is not self-adjoint, but the SelfAdjointEigensolver only needs the lower triangular part of the matrix, I think. A and B are lower triangular with zeros above the diagonal. I think this should be faster than using x * A + std::conj(x) * A.adjoint() + B + B.adjoint()

@chtz Ok, thanks. My code compiled, but there is a typo in the question. I will correct it. I am using clang

Re "I think this should be faster than using x * A + std::conj(x) * A.adjoint() + B + B.adjoint()": It will be faster, but the lower half of that and the lower half of x*A + B will rarely match (maybe if A and B are strictly lower triangular matrices).
